# RenderTargetBitmap is not capturing WebView Content in Windows phone 8.1 WinRT App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am trying to take screenshot of Webview Control using below code:

```
async Task<RenderTargetBitmap> CaptureToStreamAsync(FrameworkElement uielement, IRandomAccessStream stream, Guid encoderId)
  {
      try
      {
          var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
          await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(uielement);
          var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
          var logicalDpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
          var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderId, stream);
          encoder.SetPixelData(
              BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
              BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
              (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
              (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
              logicalDpi,
              logicalDpi,
              pixels.ToArray());

          await encoder.FlushAsync();
          return renderTargetBitmap;

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          DisplayMessage(ex.Message);
      }

      return null;
  }

RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(RenderedGrid);
RenderedImage.Source = renderTargetBitmap;
```

But I am getting blank image. 
It works fine for all other controls.
Please help!

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to capture using RenderTargetBitmap but you can use: **CapturePreviewToStreamAsync**

[WebView.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.capturepreviewtostreamasync.aspx)

Also take a look a the sample for WebView:

[XAML WebView control sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7)

Comment: I want to capture the screenshot of entire screen including webview not only webview.

Comment: In that case may I suggest you a tricky solution.
Wrap the WebView in a Grid with a empty Image control, so when you want to render the whole screen of the phone, first use CapturePreviewToStreamAsync and then set the source of the image to be the captured stream. After this change the visibility of the webview to collapsed and the visibility of the Image to visible.
After you can use the rendertargetbitmap with no problems because where you had the webview now there's an image screenshot.

I know it very tricky stuff but it should work :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to capture screenshot of Webview on Windows phone. Please see below link:

[Limitation of RenderTargetBitmap](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5aecf099-603b-46ef-990b-2aae06025c18/screenshot-from-webview?forum=wpdevelop)